TypeError: Cannot read property 'startLoadWithResult' of null, js engine: hermes
I am facing issues like the above image
it's completely working in Android but when i click on button for open web view then shows me an error in IOS only for
It shows me after updating my Expo version
and if i' trying to update web view version then show me different different error
Please help me for it.

change version of webview but not working it
